# Algorithm to check if path exists

Tags: algorithms

Suppose that I have a 2D array $B[i,j], 1 \le i,j \le n,$ such that $B[i,j]=X$ or $B[i,j] = O$. I want to write a program to check if there is a path that exists from $B[1,1]$ to $B[n,n]$ that only consist of $O$'s. The path must only consist of the 4 directions: North, South, East, West and does not include the diagonal direction. The algorithm is not necessarily looking for the shortest path, if such a path exists, just the existence of the path is needed.

I haven't formally studied algorithms but I think that this problem is a standard one in that area of study. I am not sure what to search in google though. Can anyone direct me to references on how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), and [reachability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability) in undirected graphs.  That will show you how to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @D.W.! At the top of your head, do you know of existing example code for input data represented as a 2D array? It's fine if you don't, I'll try looking for one.